# Multiple child class defines structure type used

Tags: c++, inheritance

A trouble is, I need to find a way to use different struct in object of child classes depending on which class it is.

Main class `Skeleton` is a parent for `SkeletonBVH` and `SkeletonASFAMC`
Parent struct `Bone` is inherted by `BoneBVH` and `BoneASFAMC`.
Then, I'm using struct `Bone` in a `Skeleton` class.

Is there a possibility to exchange it for `BoneBVH` in `SkeletonBVH` and `BoneASFAMC` in `SkeletonASFAMC`?

Comment: Please post what you have tried and point out where you see the problem(s).

Comment: Currently, I've converted `Bone` and derived structures to classes.
`Skeleton` class stores `Bones` using vector container.

In `SkeletonBVH` I'm upcasting `BoneBVH` pointers to `Bone` pointers, and feed those to vector container. The problem is, vector does not seems to store them properly, as downcalsting back to `BoneBVH` both with `dynamic_cast` and `static_cast` does not work as expected

Comment: Please understand that most people here prefer to see code rather than a description of the code.

Comment: Similar problem was described and solved here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/3difl2/vector_of_objects_derived_from_base_class_cant/
Still, thanks R Sahu for help :)